# ValueInjector with Dynamic Proxy objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco, valueinjecter

I have the standard repository pattern with a service layer and I need to map a POCO object called Game:

```
public class Game
{    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int GameTypeId { get; set; }
    public int GameStateId { get; set; }
    public int? PreviousGameId { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartOn { get; set; }
}
```

to map it to a view model that has a member called GameId. So **Id > GameId**.

However when I create my mapping convention the object is coming in with what looks like a  GUID attached to the end of it.

How can I get value injector to map these POCO objects properly without mapping from the dynamic proxy to a POCO.. or is that not possible?

Comment: you should show the full code for your model and viewmodel, and show the source Property in M and target property in VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up turning off proxy generation and lazy loading and now I just eagar load everything

Answer (score 0):

Saw the same problem today with Entity Framework Dynamic Proxies.  Here's how to make ValueInjecter work without disabling proxies.

I had used Mapper.AddMap to create a custom map, based on the non-proxy class.  At run-time my call to Mapper.Map did not get matched to my map because it received the proxy class.

```
var customerInput = Mapper.Map<CustomerInput>(customer); //runs default map
```

When I called Mapper.Map with both input and output types it worked!

```
var customerInput = Mapper.Map<Customer, CustomerInput>(customer); //runs custom map
```

Answer (score -1):

Try doing an explicit cast of the proxy to the underlying POCO'S type before mapping it.

Comment: Casting the input object for the Mapper.Map does not cause a custom map to be selected.  Map still sees the prior type.